# Need the simple way get arrays of coordinates from geojson

Tags: python, python-3.x, geojson

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
```

I want to get arrays of coordinates from Geojson file I have.

Down below is the sample of contents in file I opened.

```
gdf1 = gpd.read_file(fn)
print(gdf1)

      N02_001 N02_002     N02_003         N02_004                                           geometry
0          23       5  沖縄都市モノレール線       沖縄都市モノレール  LINESTRING (127.67948 26.21454, 127.67970 26.2...
1          12       5    いわて銀河鉄道線  アイジーアールいわて銀河鉄道  LINESTRING (141.29139 40.33740, 141.29176 40.3...
2          12       5    いわて銀河鉄道線  アイジーアールいわて銀河鉄道  LINESTRING (141.27554 40.23936, 141.27567 40.2...
3          12       5    いわて銀河鉄道線  アイジーアールいわて銀河鉄道  LINESTRING (141.28659 40.26092, 141.28538 40.2...
4          12       5    いわて銀河鉄道線  アイジーアールいわて銀河鉄道  LINESTRING (141.29082 40.28615, 141.29089 40.2...
```

I filtered it.

```
all_wthcl = gdf1[gdf1.N02_003==linename]
only_cor =all_wthcl["geometry"]
print(only_cor)

15597    LINESTRING (140.20076 35.68626, 140.19987 35.6...
15598    LINESTRING (140.68460 35.72969, 140.68210 35.7...
15599    LINESTRING (140.49187 35.66233, 140.48968 35.6...
15600    LINESTRING (140.82610 35.72950, 140.82596 35.7...
15601    LINESTRING (140.31649 35.66363, 140.31628 35.6...
                               ...
15700    LINESTRING (140.10267 35.62336, 140.10214 35.6...
15701    LINESTRING (139.96020 35.70700, 139.96272 35.7...
15702    LINESTRING (139.96430 35.70510, 139.96536 35.7...
15703    LINESTRING (139.96004 35.70682, 139.96239 35.7...
15704    LINESTRING (139.96430 35.70510, 139.96478 35.7...
```

but I could't get the result I want to get(want to make it array or get values from it).

```
testvar =  np.array(only_cor)
print(testvar)
Name: geometry, Length: 108, dtype: geometry
[<shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x0000021E039E7188>
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x0000021E039E7308>
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x0000021E039E7488>
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x0000021E039E7608>
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x0000021E039E7788>
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x0000021E039E7908>
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x0000021E039E7A88>
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x0000021E039E7C08>
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x0000021E039E5E88>
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x0000021E039E5FC8>
....
]
```

The last one I tried to get values from filtered data

```
testvar =  only_cor.values
print(testvar)
<GeometryArray>
[<shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x0000016528336188>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x0000016528336308>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x0000016528336488>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x0000016528336608>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x0000016528336788>,
```

Please let me know what should I do.

thanks.

### added) I got the solution with "dict".

It could be an easier way to manage features by opening the file as a "dict" format with json, not geoseries with geopandas,
I'm sure there are more efficient way to solve this(just like the answer below on this question) but I hope this could help others suffering same problem.

```
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)['features']
    coords = []
    for iv in data:
        lanename = iv["properties"]["N02_003"]
        if lanename == "総武線":
            templst = iv['geometry']['coordinates']
            for i in templst:
                coords.append(i)
    print(coords)
    print("end")
```

Answer (score 0):

Shapely's `LineString` object has a [`coords` property](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html), which when cast to a list will contain a list of tuples of coordinates:

```py
>>> from shapely.geometry import LineString
>>> line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1)])
...
>>> list(line.coords)
[(0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0)]
```

You can iterate over `testvar` and get that property from each:

```py
coordinates = []
for _ in testvar:
    coordinates.append(list(_.coords))
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, I didn't know that "coords" property exists. Actually, I found other way to do not use geopandas. Just open the file as a "dict". I posted that on the bottom of this article. Anyway, I think I can use the solution you suggested for further plan of mine here.(It seems more simple and clearer than my one. gonna test with it.) Many thanks!